# iOS: When adding object as a property listener, do I have to "unregister" the listener before releasing my object?

Tags: c, ios, listener

As I registered the my object as a property listener. Is it necessary for me to perform any sort of "unlistening" before I release the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not continue to observe objects you are not retaining (this applies to KVO, delegation, notification, any any other listener pattern). Here is the danger:

- You observe an object ("observed") and retain it.
- Some other object also retains "observed"
- You release "observed"
- You deallocate
- "observed" changes a property and notifies you
- The program crashes

While there are several patterns that you may believe make the above impossible, they are all much more fragile than just unregistering yourself when you release the observed object, particularly in your dealloc.

Comment: Hi! I did a `AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,                                   self);`, so how do I release the release the observed?

Comment: AudioSessionRemovePropertyListenerWithUserData()

Comment: Great it works! Thanks. I realize this method is inside the api reference just that I wasn't clear. This is the first time I'm working with a C class. Now I have a better idea what to do in these situations (register property listener, remove property listener). Thanks again!